# How do I read the first page of google result with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to read the first result on a google webpage, I have tried everything feels like nothing works, it only seems to give me error: line 13, in 
result = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range How do I open that link??my code is:

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('https://google.com')
time.sleep(0)
search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('Pine martens')
time.sleep(0)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
result = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li")[0]
result.find_element_by_xpath("./div/h3/a").click()```
````

Comment: Can you give us the exact error you are encountering? Copy and paste it into your post. Also not sure what the webdriver variable is, if you could supply us with that that'd be helpful

Comment: I guess nowadays it is unclear what the "first result" is. It could be an ad, a image, a new entry or a widget, like a calulator. Also you might simplyfy and speed up the script by calling the query directly: https://google.com?q=Pine+martens

Comment: yeah I just want to learn, by searching the first result I mean the first webpage, it's ok if it's an ad.

Comment: The problem here is that your xpath isn't matching anything. Therefore, *browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li")* is returning an empty list

Comment: yeah ik the problem I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'hl')]//h3/parent::a # This xpath Points to the "a" tags of the heading
```

Instead of `time.sleep` opt for `Explicte` or `Implicit` waits.

```
# Imports Required for Explicit waits:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver. ... 
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=Pine+martens&oq=Pine+martens&aqs=chrome..69i57.228j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser,30)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[starts-with(@class,'hl')]//h3/parent::a")))

options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'hl')]//h3/parent::a")
options[0].click() # Clicks on the first link
```

Links to refer - [Link 1](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/),  [Link 2](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: this give me error element not intractable: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

Comment: Well, I have tried with that code, it works without any exception.

Comment: Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Are you using chrome? Also, I am try to click on the first website, like for this, wikipedia.

Comment: When I try just printing options I get this: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9DACEEA2-D2F6-4289-AE40-65F16B11D295", element="node-EA1D5C9E-42E8-46F8-9CD1-472656D524B8" and it repeats something like this a couple times.

Comment: Yes, I am using Chrome driver. Can you update the code in the question?